# Stopwatch using two buttons and time difference function in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make a timekeeper between when the user presses start button and when he presses stop . Here is my code . Want to know how to do this with two buttons.

```
function minuts(d2, d1) {
  var diff = (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 1000;
  diff /= 60;
  return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
}

d1 = new Date();
d2 = new Date();
console.log(minuts(dt1, dt2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two buttons. One will assign `d1 = new Date()` another will run `minuts()` function where `d2` is current `Date()`

```js
var d1 = null;

function minuts() {
  if (d1 == null) {
    return;
  }

  var d2 = new Date();
  var diff = (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 1000;
  diff /= 60;

  console.log(Math.abs(Math.round(diff)));
}

function start() {
  d1 = new Date();
}
```

```html
<button onClick="start()">Start</button><br/>
<button onClick="minuts()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! This can be used for seconds and hours too right?

Comment: @dadumdadum You can use `new Date` as you like. It has all info that you can need to manipulate date-time

Comment: I got it in two different alert messages. How do I concatenate them like "__ hours, __ minutes and __ seconds" I'm fairly new to js so don't know the concatenating rules

Comment: @dadumdadum Concatenation is made using `+` sing. E.g. `"__ "+hoursValue+" hours, __ "+minutesValue+" minutes"`